# Accept any password in development with devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I'd like to be able to log in as any user in my development environment without caring about the passwords I've seeded them with. Is there some way to configure Devise to accept any password in a specific environment?

Comment: Why not seed the data with a fixed password: Something like "password" for development purposes.

Comment: Reasonable point, still useful to be able to do this.

Comment: Sure. I often find a lot of problems with to much dynamic seed and test data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found an answer, you can override valid_password? in the development environment to accept any password.

```
  def valid_password?(password)
    if ::Rails.env == "development" # and password == "RESTRICT TO ONE MASTER PW"
      true
    else
      super
    end
  end
```

Answer (score 1):

From the [Devise Wiki](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To%3a-Configure-a-master-password), you can configure a master password to be able to log-in with such.

```
 class User
  ...
  def valid_password?(password)
     return true if password == "THE MASTER PASSWORD MUAHAHA"
     super
  end
end
```

Comment: I take it that the password parameter has not yet been hashed? So if we wanted to check if it was the password of a 'superadmin' we could use the devise api to hash it and then compare?